# How to recreate this basic ALPS switch board in Arduino?

Tags: wires, switch

I want to recreate this existing ALPS switch board (the board on the left) in Arduino, so I can control the switches (and 3 memory + 1 menu buttons) from my laptop. The ALPS switch board connects to a controller board (PSM) with relays, microprocessor, and DC motors connected to it.
[image: ALPS Switch Board + PSM]

The idea is to use Arduino to completely replace the ALPS switch board, while still preserving the controller board connection and current wiring and connector (16 pins + 2 empty pins).

Is there a way I can just connect the 16-pin connector directly to header pins on a certain Arduino variant? And program the individual pins, to replicate the manual switch input + 4 buttons?

[image: Pin diagram]
See pin diagram attached (seen from the other end of the wiring, on the controller board side), where I get a little bit confused about terminal #C4 - #C7.

If easily possible, I want to use the controller board power, not the Arduino power.
I’m also not sure about what the 2000 Ohm resistor on the left side does exactly.

Edit 1:
Hopefully the new picture above clears things up a bit. The switch board connects to a PSM (Power Seat Module), which controls the DC motors of an early 2000s car power seat (don't think the OEM matters here). I want to control the PSM with my Arduino (so I don't have to use the ALPS board anymore). In other words, I have to replicate all the functionality from the ALPS board with my Arduino.

Edit 2: A picture of underside of Alps board:
[image: Underside of Alps board]

Edit 3: 
The P/N for the switch board is: ALPS ANJ971038D RH DR. And for the PSM (which includes the relays): ALPS ANV971018A. There is no public documentation that I found for any of the 2 boards. The pinout diagram above is from the dealership, but I'm not allowed to post further details about it.

Here are the results of what I measured myself using my multimeter. When the switch board is powered from the PSM I measured 4,5V on the + and - of the 4 memory buttons in neutral position. By pressing a memory butting the voltage drops to 0V. The + and - on the white switches measured 11,90V in neutral position. According to the pinout diagram the voltage is supposed to drop to 0V, but this didn't happen when I moved the switch while measuring. I also measured a resistance of 1490 Ohm between pin 2 and 5 of a white switch (so the neutral position), while the switch board was being powered! No resistance when the board is disconnected from the PSM.

I also measured pin #C4 and #C6/7 right from the connector, and I got 0,99V. #C5 and #C6-7 gave me 2,95V. Pin #C4 and #C5 are connected to the resistor (R1).

The switches are all momentary switches.

2 pictures of sketches/measurement results:
[image: Pin measurement diagram]
[image: ALPS board measurement results sketch]

Comment: I think there's not enough information given for anyone to say (unless they happen to have that same board, and can read your mind to discover what you want to do).   Please edit your question to include the part number and model number the board is out of.    Please edit your question to indicate which switch connects to which pin, which switches are momentary or latching, and draw a picture of before and after  – ie, where the switch board is now, with what it connects to, and where you want it after whatever the conversion is.

Comment: Yes you could do that, if you could find the matching half of the connector.  You then run the leads off to your Arduino and write a program to do what you want.  How you do it is anyone's guess, but you could do it.

Comment: Before we can answer this question we will need a little more information from you. I can see that this board is for an electronic seat adjustment system. Do you want to replace the board in the picture with an Arduino or do you want to keep it and have the board control an Arduino? Also, what car is this board from?

Comment: @Matt I just edited. Is it more clear for you now?

Comment: @jwpat7 I just added more details. I think the pin diagram is clear enough on what pin connects to what switch, right? Which switch is doing what is printed on the switch board. All of the switches are in neutral mode as you can see on the picture. If you manually move the switch left or right or up or down, a signal will be send to the PSM and the motors to change the seat position. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: That's much better. You probably wont find an off the shelf Arduino variant which would directly accept the plug but you can use an Arduino Uno with the Proto shield and wire up your own headers.  Please could you upload a picture of the underside of the ALPS switchboard and I'll try and figure out what that resistor is for.

Comment: @Matt Okay sounds good! Someone also told me I should use 8 relays (8 actions in total with the manual switches). I don't know why he said that or why I need it, if I can just directly program the pins from Arduino? (Still leaves open the question about the meaning of #C4 - #C7) Underside pic: https://imgur.com/a/CKSDZ

Comment: I was assuming you'd make some sort of graphical user interface on the software side which will replace the switches which will program the pins, so i'm not sure why they said that. That picture looks good, I'll get right on figuring out what the resistor does. Would it be possible for you to trace the wires to figure out which pins are connected on both ends? I'm not 100% sure but i think the #C4 and #C5 pins are used for diagnostics (The ECU uses them to check whether the board is connected and will bring up a fault code if not). I have a few people i can ask

Comment: Please could you get a picture of the board with the switches (Switches up pointing up like this picture at the top of this page) as top down as possible, i'm having a hard time seeing all the traces as some of them are hidden by the switches

Comment: CocoaNut, since the cable wiring at the Alps board end has a different pinout than the relay board end, you still should say which switch connects to which pin, and which switches are momentary or latching.  Also include all the documentation links and part numbers you have available, such as for the Alps board, the relay board, the PSM.  This will save time for people who are trying to help, by allowing them to find stuff on the web.   For example, there apparently is some document that you got the relay board pinout diagram from; what's the doc's name, and where is it found?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I indeed want to make a GUI! But after talking to an Arduino webshop guy, he also recommended me to use relays, based on the fact the switches are supplied with Ubat. So I measured 11,90V on 4 of the 6 switch pins when in neutral position. According to the pin diagram the voltage is supposed to drop to 0V as long as the switch is operated. When I operated the switch the voltage didn't change at all though on my multimeter.

I'll update my question later to reflect this information.

Comment: @Matt When I have my multimeter set to 2000 Ohm, it’ll either give me 1979 Ohm or 001 between C4/C5 and the resistor! So looks like you’re right :-)!

I also measured 0,99V and 2,95V on the C4-C7 circuits. Here’s a picture from a better angle: https://imgur.com/a/8bpZo (my Stack reputation doesn’t allow me to add it to the question).

Comment: Relays are good but as they are a mechanical device they have a higher rate of failure than a solid state device. I have personally used these MOSFETS in many projects and would highly recommend them http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/10PCS-IRLB3034-IRLB3034PBF-HEXFET-Power-MOSFET-TO-220-NEW-/191736129878?hash=item2ca45d2956:g:n7cAAOSwI-BWQvbo     Here's the data sheet  http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlb3034pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566027b22585

Comment: Have you been able to trace the wires between the plugs, as soon as you send me that information i will be able to start designing you a control board. Also, which Arduino would you like to use? I'd recommend an Arduino nano as they can be very easily integrated in to a custom circuit board.

Comment: @Matt Interesting, didn't know that! Thanks! I've been busy collecting answers, I hope to be able to update my post soon. I ordered some Arduino gear yesterday already. I have an Arduino Uno R3, Relay Shield v3.0 (4 relays, couldn't find one (in stock) with 8 relays), RedBear BLE Shield and an ARDX starter kit, so I have some extra components, wiring, breadboard, etc. The Arduino Nano looks good for a later stage in the project I think! (Same for MOSFETS, as it looks like it needs to be custom made, not an off the shelf shield)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GNR6K13.jpg   This is a picture of my most recent project's control board with the nano in the middle. Hopefully we'll be able to make something like this for your use-case or even get a custom PCB made but they can be expensive. If you don't mind me asking, what is your background? Have you got much electronics or programming experience?

Comment: @Matt Super cool! Looks exciting! Sorry it took me so long, but  I just added the extra information! (Still figuring out how to answer the "momentary or latching" question from yesterday.) Is this good enough for you? I have done some iOS projects and UI/UX design projects. So not a lot of electronics or Arduino programming experience. Do you have a website or a way to chat outside of this comments section ;)? I'm seeing a warning now to "avoid extended discussions in comments" ;-)

Comment: @jwpat7 Just added the details. Thanks for pushing ;-)!

Comment: CocoaNut, great, +1.  Note, the pinout voltages in diagram might be what you should see with cables attached both ends and under power, vs only one end hooked up. @Matt, you can flag the moderator to move the discussion to Arduino.stackexchange chat, if you want, which will key the discussion to the question.  Or just click on StackExchange, at top left corner of this page, then click 'chat' in the CURRENT COMMUNITY section, and open a chat.